# Feedback on voice-recognition software for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, speech-recognition

I'd like to get some feedback on any of the voice recognition software that is available for Linux. Free or paid..

That can type on any program and have enter key and right mouse click.  I'm currently using NaturallySpeaking..

Would like to switch from Windows 10. Thank you

Comment: You can start here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_software_for_Linux]